# Backward matching of the unlabeled trailing closure is deprecated... Any way to silence it, instead of stopping use of trailing closure?

Tags: swift

Swift compiler today surprised me with new cool feature.. warning :

```
Backward matching of the unlabeled trailing closure is deprecated; label the argument with 'onSuccess' to suppress this warning
```

I use trailing closure syntax almost everywhere and I don't see where is the issue with this case.

Function is defined as this:

```
func send<Data>(operation: CSOperation<Data>, title: String, progress: Bool = true,
        canCancel: Bool = true, failedDialog: Bool = true, onInternetFailed: (() -> Void)? = nil,
        onSuccess: ((Data) -> Void)? = nil) -> CSProcess<Data> {}
```

It was called like this:

```
send(operation: model.server.downloadCensusDocument(), title: .page_thanks_confirmation_download) {
        documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: $0.url)
        ...
    }
```

And compiler wants me to write it like this:

```
    send(operation: model.server.downloadCensusDocument(), title: .page_thanks_confirmation_download, onSuccess: {
        documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: $0.url)
        ...
    })
```

Any way to silence it, instead of stopping use of trailing closure ?

Comment: Two other options: 1. Make `onSuccess` not an optional. That resolves the ambiguity, too. 2. You might also consider refactoring with a single completion handler closure, `(Result<Data, Error>) -> Void`, which makes it even more clear that `Data` will be returned on `.success` and that `Error` will be returned on `.failure`. It makes the contract a little more clear.

Comment: Interesting proposals @Rob I'll check it out...

Answer (score 8):

As you're probably aware, the key new feature is that both the `onInternetFailed:` function and the `onSuccess:` parameter are now allowed to be trailing closures. Multiple trailing closures. The rule is that when you do that, the *first* one is not labeled and the *others* are labelled, with no comma. So:

```
send(....) {
    // onInternetFailed function body
} onSuccess: {
    // onSuccess function body
}
```

Okay, but then the problem here is: there are two *optional* trailing closures, so if you omit one, which one are you omitting?

You are assuming that you are omitting the *first* one. The compiler understands that you think that, and it permits this omission, but with a warning, temporarily, because eventually it will become illegal — or, to put it more technically, eventually it will be assumed that the omitted one is the *second* one.

To avoid the warning, therefore, you must include both closures.

So, I would now write

```
send(operation: model.server.downloadCensusDocument(),
    title: .page_thanks_confirmation_download) 
        {} onSuccess: {
             documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: $0.url)
            //...
        }
```

That silences the warning and I don't think it looks too bad. Both closures trail, and the first one is just empty.

Comment: See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/swift-5-3-and-trailing-closures/ for more info.

Comment: Even editor automatically knows that it is last one and will auto fix it for me, so sure compiler could know too and pick the same automatically as it is without warning, but I know I am asking in wrong place :)

Comment: No, read what said here and in the article (and what it ways in the official language proposal). It is cutting you some slack now, so it is warning you only. But in future it will be the first one and your code would break if you didn’t change it.